# Couldn't access response outside the function

Tags: javascript

```js
const sendRequest = async() => {
  const response = await fetch("the api", {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      'Authorization': getAccessToken(),
      "x-sc-identity": "external"
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      "Name": "somethibng",
      "TemplateID": "something"
    })

  })
  console.log("response", response);
  return response;
}

await sendRequest();

dispatch(setPropertyList(response))
```

Passing response to `dispatch(setPropertyList(response))` gives error:

> Cannot find name 'response'

I couldn't access the request as it is inside a function and its function scoped !

Comment: You can't use `await` outside of `async` function

Comment: @decpk This whole code is inside another async function. I dint paste it here because i would be so clumsy !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `response` is only defined inside the function, and is the value returned. The identifier does not exist outside the function. You need to use the result of the call of `sendRequest` - use its return value.

```
const response = await sendRequest();
dispatch(setPropertyList(response))
```